# Edit Google Drive Embed Audio Player

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-drive-api

I need to embed some audio files from Google Drive into my WebSite. I'm able to embed, it works just fine, the problem is, I can't edit the player (Picture below).
[image: audioPlayer]

There is anyway I can do this?

```html
<iframe 
  frameborder="0" 
  width="100%"     
  height="70"
  src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XcG5vGKQmapAZBQW9yTI901-XBzGBpo8/preview?usp=sharing">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO7aB5E9xLI has presented two ways how to embed mp3 from dgrive, the second one getting you direct way to the mp3 which you could embed with audio tag in your page then I suppose you could hide it and make design of your own player and via javascript do some actions with emeded audio player.
So look here ...